# Flutter Firebase_messaging onBackgroundMessage is not called on older ios devices (iPhone 7 iPhone 8)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, callkit

We are using firebase_messaging ^9.1.1 in our flutter app. onBackgroundMessage is being called in 'iPhone se' when app is in background or in terminated state.  But is in not being called on iPhone 7 or iPhone 8.  IOS version is same in all the devices i.e. IOS 14.4.2.

We are calling callkeep: ^0.2.3+1 plugin in onBackgroundMessage. We can't see call UI when app is terminated/in background and receive notification (iPhone 7 or iPhone 8).

This is our code:

```
void main() async {
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myBackgroundMessageHandler);

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
if (!UniversalPlatform.isWeb) {
PushNotificationsManager().initCallKit();
}
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();
//callkeep: ^0.2.3+1 plugin. code here.
}

Have anyone faced this issue? what next we can try to solve this issue?
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?